# Remove AnyObject from Swift dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
var dict:[NSObject:[AnyObject]]
```

I want to remove an object from the dictionary by value.

```
func removeObject(anObject:AnyObject) {
    for key in dict.keys {
        dict[key] = dict[key]!.filter({$0 == anObject})
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'AnyObject' operands
```

What's the best way to remove this object?  I want to keep it generic as possible.

Comment: Are they referentially equivalent? If so, use `===`.

Comment: You cannot compare `AnyObject` because maybe the first object is `Circle` and the second object is `Giraffe`, how can you compare them? if you to downcast and only then cmpare

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, one option is to use NSObject instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835359/compare-two-nsobject-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: This seems to work: `func removeObject(anObject:AnyObject) {
    for key in dict.keys {
        dict[key] = dict[key]!.filter({$0 !== anObject})
    }
}`

Comment: Do you really mean `!==`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove object that are *semantically equal* to `anObject`, it and the elements in the array must conform to the `Equatable` protocol. Make a your function a generic one like this:

```
var dict = [NSObject:[AnyObject]]()

dict["key1"] = [1,2,3,"Hello world"]
dict["key2"] = [3,4,5]

func removeObject<T: Equatable>(anObject: T) {
    for key in dict.keys {
        dict[key] = dict[key]!.filter {
            if let element = $0 as? T where element == anObject {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}

// Remove all number 3
removeObject(3)

print(dict)
```

Note that this can have some odd results:

```
dict["key1"] = [1, 2, 3]
dict["key2"] = [4, 3.4, 3.9]

removeObject(3.0)    // 3.4 and 3.9 remain
removeObject(3)      // 3.4 and 3.9 gone
```

That's because 3.4 and 3.9 become 3 when you cast them as `Int`